# sync wifi credentials across Mac devices?

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, ipad, macbook-air, icloud

I have an iPhone 4S, a new iPad and a MacBook Air. I haven't found this anywhere: want to know if there's a way to sync all the wi-fi credentials across all these devices. For example, I go into a café with my computer and log in the secure WiFi with a password they give me. After a few days I drop by the café with my iPhone, I would love to have it connect automatically due to me having connected in my MBA a few days back.

Possible? Is there an APP FOR THAT?

Thanks